# XML file signature by X509Certificate for vbnet

Tags: xml, vb.net

welcome everybody
I want to know how the xml file is signed with certificate = X509Certificate
And make a hash of the file
programming language vbnet

I have attached an example on this link. I want to sign the file and know how to create some symbols. Thank you all
[enter link description here](https://www.proands.com/2022-08-05-030150.xml)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and which part of your code didn't lead to the expected results?

Comment: I have attached all the files

Answer (score 0):

Look

{"The signature key is not loaded."}

[image]

```
 Private Sub SignWithCerButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SignWithCerButton.Click

    ' Variables
    Try


        Dim bResult As Boolean = False
        Dim pCertContext As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim key As RSA = Nothing
        Dim doc As XmlDocument = Nothing
        Dim signedXml As SignedXml = Nothing
        Dim reference As Reference = Nothing
        Dim trns As XmlDsigC14NTransform = Nothing
        Dim env As XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform = Nothing
        Dim keyInfo As KeyInfo = Nothing
        Dim xmlDigitalSignature As XmlElement = Nothing
        Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = Nothing
        Dim pass As SecureString = Nothing
        ' Generate a signing key from the subject certificate.
        pass = New SecureString()
        pass.AppendChar("p")
        pass.AppendChar("a")
        pass.AppendChar("s")
        pass.AppendChar("s")
        pass.AppendChar("w")
        pass.AppendChar("o")
        pass.AppendChar("r")
        pass.AppendChar("d")
        cert = New X509Certificate2(ToVerifyTextBox.Text, "123345")
        key = cert.PrivateKey

        ' Create a new XML document.
        doc = New XmlDocument
        ' Format using white spaces.
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = True
        ' Load the passed XML.
        doc.Load(TextBox2.Text)
        ' Create a SignedXml object.
        signedXml = New SignedXml(doc)
        ' Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = key
        ' Create a reference to be signed.
        reference = New Reference
        reference.Uri = ""
        ' Add a transformation to the reference.
        trns = New XmlDsigC14NTransform
        reference.AddTransform(trns)
        ' Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        env = New XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform
        reference.AddTransform(env)
        ' Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference)
        ' Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).

        'keyInfo = New KeyInfo
        'keyInfo.AddClause(New RSAKeyValue(CType(Key, RSA)))
        'signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo
        ' Create a new KeyInfo object.
        keyInfo = New KeyInfo()
        ' Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
        ' and add it to the KeyInfo object.
        ' keyInfo.AddClause(New KeyInfoX509Data(cert))
        ' Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo
        ' Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature()
        ' Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        ' it to an XmlElement object.
        xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml()
        ' Append the element to the XML document.
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, True))
        If TypeOf doc.FirstChild Is XmlDeclaration Then
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild)
        End If
        ' Show the signature
        ToVerifyTextBox.Text = doc.OuterXml
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I have uploaded the example for you on my site, all the signature files are attached to the water of that certificate and The private and public key

[enter link description here](https://www.proands.com/WindowsApp3.zip)

**Thank you for your attention**

[image]